# Importing MySQL dump on shell with variable in filename

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, vagrant

In a Dev Env I use the db-name for both username and password. In my Vagrant bootstrap.sh I have following lines:

```
dbname=master
...
/usr/bin/mysql -u ${dbname} -p${dbname} ${dbname} < /vagrant/vagrant/tmp/latest-${dbname}.sql
```

On vagrant up I get the error

```
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 273: id: command not found
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 273: email: command not found
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 273: phone: command not found
...
```

with email etc. beeing columns of a to-be-imported table. I interpret this such that my sql file is beeing executed as bash script instead of beeing piped to mysql. If I run the same command via ssh after vagrant up finished, everything works. Where´s my error?

Comment: try dbname="master" and then use it like "$dbname"

Comment: @BallPython, I never understood that difference. Please could you explain? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Making me thing half a day, it hit me 5 minutes after posting the question:

mysqldump escapes column names with backticks. When used in the bootstrap.sh, those backticks are interpreted by linux' backtick operator.

Solution is to execute mysqldump with the

```
--skip-quote-names
```

parameter